# PHP empty not working

Tags: php

I am just trying to check if a form variable is empty. The code sets the variables `$getsubject` and `$getsubject` to the `$_POST` of the form, then I am checking if they are, empty and if they are I want to set them to `"No Message"` or `"No Subject"`. I tried with `isset` as well and it didn't work. I even tried setting an else statement that does the same thing and it doesn't change it.

```
$getsubject = $_POST['subject'];
$getmessage = $_POST['message'];

if(empty($getsubject)) {    
    $getsubject = "<No Subject>";
}

if(empty($getmessage)){ 
    $getmessage = "<No Message>";
}
```

Comment: Do you ever `echo` `$getmessage` ? If not, of course it won't display.

Comment: What do you get if you try a `var_dump($getsubject)` after you initially assign to the variable, as well as after your `empty` check?

Comment: Are you using a html form? Could you show the code?

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem .. the code is working - however the since there were brackets "<" and ">" ... when I retrieved the data from the SQL table, it was not appearing. Not sure why, but when I removed the brackets it worked.

Comment: The why was because the browser saw the `< >` and thought you where outputting html, if you viewed source you would see it

Comment: If you want to use `<` and `>` symbols in your code, you have to use `&lt;` and `&gt;` in order for them to echo, "IF" that was your original intent.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure id the data from the form exist you must use !isset to check it before you  declare the variables, so:

```
if(!isset($getsubject)) {    
    $getsubject = "<No Subject>";
}
else{
$getsubject = $_POST['subject'];
}

if(!isset($getmessage)){ 
    $getmessage = "<No Message>";
}
else{
$getmessage = $_POST['message'];
}
```

The data from `$_POST['subject'];`, for example, might not exist, and if you declare it php will give you an error

Answer (score -2):

I suggest that you use a full if conditional to display the results you are looking for combined with html.

IF subject has content 
    then echo Great subject
ELSE 
    then echo No Subject
END IF

IF message has content 
    then echo Thank You for the message
ELSE 
    then echo No Messgae was entered
END IF

^this is the basic logic not the code
Also look into the trim php code which will trim blank space off of the submission. This helps eliminate blank responses or spaces counting as characters (will not remove space between characters)